# Persist logged-in user in MERN Application

Tags: authentication, cookies, jwt, mern, httponly

What are some of the best practices to persist logged-in user?
I was using JWT and storing it in `localStorage` but found that using `localStorage` is not safe.
Should I store JWT in `httpOnly` cookie?
Should I even use JWT for this purpose since some articles suggest not using it? I am confused.

I tried to search for it on google but found that most of them were using JWT by storing it in `localStorage`.